# AttributeError when I execute a python script

Tags: python, postgresql

When I execute a python script  to assign my database in postgres, I get this Error !!

"AttributeError 'psycopg2._psycopg.cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only "

```
def ma_fonction(d):
    # connexion à la base de données
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'test3' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = 'postgres'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for n in d :
        cur.execute = ("""
        PDATE douar SET distance_route = %s,  distance_piste = %s, distance_ecole = %s, distance_college = %s, distance_sante = %s, distance_souk=%s WHERE id =%s
        """,
        d[n]['route'] / 1000.0,
        d[n]['piste'] / 1000.0 ,
        d[n]['ecole'] / 1000.0,
        d[n]['college'] / 1000.0,
        d[n]['sante'] / 1000.0,
        d[n]['souk'] / 1000.0
        )
    conn.commit()
    print(commit)
```

Any solution plz !!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `=`.  It should be:

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE douar SET dist...)
```